# How to implement horizontal and vertical transition on specific pages using ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-transitions, sliding

Let's say I have 10 fragments: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J.

I want the fragment transition to be like this:

[image: fragment transition]

I want:

- A to D to be able to slide between each other vertically
- D with E horizontally
- E to G to able to slide vertically
- G with H horizontally

Is it even possible? Or is there any other way to achieve this using Fragments?

Comment: do you mean like this? https://github.com/Devlight/InfiniteCycleViewPager

Comment: almost similar. I asked that for my project, its user interface like magazine so after reach end of chapter must be slide horizontal to go other chapter

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with nested viewpager

1. Add fragments A-C in a vertical viewpager
2. Group fragments D and E in a single container fragment using a horizontal view pager and add this container fragment to your main vertical viewpager
3. Add F to your main viewpager, and make another container fragment for G and H
4. Add rest of the fragments in vertical viewpager